# MVC Action Links - All but one works?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am having an issue with my action links - I have a menu bar that shows different links based on who is logged in and they all work, except my new one and I have been stumped for hours on this (I am a noob - this is only day 3 of ASP/MVC for me). code for my menu below - it is part of my _layout.cshtml file. it is the "Secret Admin" link that is not working. The cshtml is exactly where it should be too, in the admin folder of the views. Thank you in advance!

```
<nav>
    <ul id="menu">
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
        @if(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        { 
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Admin", "Index", "Admin")</li>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("My Account", "Manage", "Account")</li>

            if(User.Identity.Name == "reecea")
            {
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Secret Admin","index2","Admin")</li>
            }
        }
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Do you have an action called "index2" on your "Admin" controller class?

Comment: What were you expecting of that if you don't have the action?

Answer (score 1):

I see that Jakob already answered your question above.  Something that you might find helpful is using a template like T4 for "MVC".  It let's you use strongly-typed objects instead of using strings in a lot of places.  Other than making it easier to create code, it will help you find places where you interrupt functionality.  For example, if you change the name of the index2 action in the future, you won't immediately know that the link is broken.